# Angular router doesn't trigger onbeforeunload in IFrame

Tags: angular

I have an IFrame inside an angular route view. When I trigger a state change in the router via `navigateByUrl` the `window.onbeforeunload` function inside the IFrame ins't triggered. Same for `addEventListern("beforunload",...)`.

First question: 
Why isn't it triggered?

Second:
Is there a way to solve this easily?

Comment: That's a DOM event and Angular is not involved. If it is not fired with Angular, it would also not be fired without Angular. Have you tried with plain JS? Perhaps the browser just doesn't support that.

Comment: `window.onbeforunload = function( ) {}` is plain JS and these callbacks are triggered when I use the page directly in a browser. It is just not triggered when I use it in an IFrame.

Comment: That might be a problem with the IFrame. I haven't used that myself. Please try to create a reproduction in http://stackblitz.com that shows how it works with plain JS and how it not works with Angular

Comment: Fixed it by using the `onpagehide` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using the `onpagehide` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `window.onunload` event. This event is triggered (together with above mentioned `window.onpagehide`) in `iframe.contentWindow` when the angular component (contaning the iframe in view) is destroyed. Then why the event `window.onbeforeunload` (which should precede `unload`) is not triggered? That's the question? :D